# Curl command not uploading file contents

Tags: spring, curl

Hi I am using cURL command to upload a file which is a POST request to my local machine service.

I am using following commands to upload

> curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F
>   "/Users/myName/Folder/file.csv" http://localhost:port/api/fileupload

In my application side I am using spring frameworks web binding to receive the file

Following is the code snippet

```
public ResponseEntity importDimensions(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) {
     // file is variable is always null
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `@` sign before the filename, like this: `@/Users/myName/Folder/file.csv`.

And if your server-side code is expecting a parameter named `file` then you need to do this:

```
-F "file=@/Users/myName/Folder/file.csv"
```

Comment: is there any doc how to use variable instead of file path literal?

Comment: let's say I have 
FILE_NAME="$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p")dev-dump.sql"

-F "file=@$FILE_NAME"
does not work